# Update info in XML from a .txt using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, updates

I have a entery.txt file with this kind of info in it  :

```
Bob, 42, 3
Ruth, 40, 5
```

I have a info.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <class>
 <student name="Class1" code="42" amount="70.00" quantity= "13" />
 <student name="Class2" code="40" amount="32.00" quantity= "100"  />
 </class>
```

The infos in the .txt file represent : the student's name, what class she's taking and the hours she'll be taking in this class.

To be clear : Bob is taking Class 1 (code 42) and will be taking 3 hours of this class.
The .txt file can be updated everyday (by "updated" I mean we can add row, not deleting it)
I want the .xml to be updated too, linked to the new infos.
If Bob is taking 3 hours, I want the quantity of Class1 now to be "10" (13-3).

So the new .xml file would be :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <class>
     <student name="Class1" code="42" amount="70.00" quantity= "10" />
     <student name="Class2" code="40" amount="32.00" quantity= "95"  />
     </class>
```

In order to do that, I want to work with Java.

So on, I only found how to linked a .java with a .xml using this code :

```
    package java_dom_parser;
        
        import java.io.IOException;
        
        import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
        import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
        import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
        
        import org.w3c.dom.Document;
        import org.w3c.dom.Element;
        import org.w3c.dom.Node;
        import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
        import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
        
        public class MyDomParser {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("class.xml");
            NodeList listeDeStudents = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
            for (int i = 0; i < listeDeStudents.getLength(); i++ ) {;
            Node p = listeDeStudents.item(i);
            
            if (p.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element student = (Element) p; 
                String quantity = student.getAttribute("quantity");
                
                System.out.println(student + quantity);
            }
            
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        
        }
```

I'm really stuck there, I don't know how I can link the file to an .txt file. I think the "modify" part will be easier when I'll know how to linked the .txt file to the .xml.

Comment: How do you know that your file has been updated?